# what are the options for win32con.DT_*? python for windows draw text

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui, drawtext

I just cant find the different options for the draw text function in python for windows.
I want the text I am drawing to be on the bottom left corner of the screen rather than the top center.
if bottom left is not an option is bottom center possible?

```
        win32gui.DrawText(hdc, windowText, -1, rect,
        win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER
    )
```

is there an option such as

```
win32con.DT_LEFT | win32con.DT_BOTTOM
```

?

I cannot find any related information online for this snippet of code on Microsoft or python docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see extensive documentation for corresponding WinAPI functions on Microsoft site:

[`DrawText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext):

> parameter ...
>
> `DT_BOTTOM`
>
> Justifies the text to the bottom of the rectangle. This value is used
>   only with the `DT_SINGLELINE` value.

As stated above, `DT_BOTTOM` works only when `DT_SINGLELINE` is specified. Therefore you need:

```
win32con.DT_LEFT | win32con.DT_BOTTOM | win32con.DT_SINGLELINE
```

---

Note, this will not be adequate for drawing multiple lines aligned to bottom of the rectangle. In that case, use `DT_CALCRECT` flag to calculate the height of the text which is to be drawn. Then offset the rectangle based on the height of that calculated rectangle. Example:

```
textformat = win32con.DT_LEFT | win32con.DT_BOTTOM
calrect = win32gui.DrawText(hdc, text, -1, rect, textformat | win32con.DT_CALCRECT);

rect.top = rect.bottom - calcrect.bottom;
win32gui.DrawText(hDC, text, -1, rect, textformat)
```